# Is it possible to extend/modify a build plugin with a sub package?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm attempting to build CSS compiler system that allows you to include just the plugins you need for your app, so a modular approach would be prefered.

Here's the scenario: Package A, for example `masterPackage`, registers a build plugin which attaches to `filename.ext`. Package B `masterPackage-extension`, depends on package A but only modifies the build plugin in package A to include additional compiler options.

I can't figure out if this is possible as the scope of the plugin handler seems restricted to the current package. Does anybody know if it is possible to extend a source handler (added with `Plugin.registerSourceHandler`) once it is declared, similar to how you can for other package files?

Keen to hear your ideas, thanks!